# Can testng test depend on test ran in a different class?

Tags: testng

Assuming both tests are in the same file, i would

```
@Test(groups="basic", dependsOnGroups="someCleverGroupName")
```

How can this be handled if my group is mentioned in the other class?

Right now, i rightfully am getting the `depends on nonexistent group` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the you include the classes that contain the methods belonging to that group in your `testng.xml`.

Comment: Any chance to do it with annotations?

Comment: That's kind of a catch-22: using classes to find which classes need to be found :-)  The only way to do this is for TestNG to scan the entire classpath. A bit expensive but TestNG admittedly already does this to support package wildcards...

Comment: Can you set dependsOnGroups inside a test tag inside the testing.xml in a similar fashion?  So that if you have multiple test tags with preserveorder=true, that one test group can depend on another succeeding?  Just curious.